# Tilde Operator in map function

Tags: r

I have a question regarding the map function  in R and the tilde operator ´~´

Why does this code only work that way:

```
iris_unique <- map(iris, ~length(unique(.)))
```

and not for example like this

```
iris_unique <- map(iris, length(unique(iris$Sepal.Length)))
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that you are talking about `map` from the package `purrr`, this function is designed to map a function over a vector.

`length(unique(iris$Sepal.Length))` is a specific value (35 for the standard `iris` dataset), so

```
iris_unique <- map(iris, length(unique(iris$Sepal.Length)))
```

is equivalent to

```
iris_unique <- map(iris, 35)
```

since `35` is not a function, this is probably not what you mean. However `map()` tries to make sense of it. [The documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/purrr/versions/0.2.5/topics/map) says that if for the function parameter you pass it a "character vector, numeric vector, or list, it is converted to an extractor function", which means that `35` is converted to the function `function(x){x[35]}`, hence the net result is to extract the 35th observation of `iris`.

On the other hand, the documentation also describes how it translates formulas into functions. According to that, the formula `~length(unique(.))` is translated to the function `function(x){length(unique(x))}`. Since this is a function, it makes perfect sense to map it over a list or vector.