# effect of tilda in purrr::map

Tags: r, functional-programming, purrr

Regarding the discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53651405/tilde-operator-in-map-function) and map [documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/purrr/versions/0.2.5/topics/map) ("**If character vector, numeric vector, or list, it is converted to an extractor function**"), shouldn't the following two statements result in the same output?
map documentation :

```
map(1:3,  function(x){x[runif(2)]})
[[1]]
integer(0)

[[2]]
integer(0)

[[3]]
integer(0)
```

and

```
map(1:3,  runif(2))
[[1]]
NULL

[[2]]
NULL

[[3]]
NULL
```

I wonder why the outputs are different.

Comment: The second one is trying to do this: `runif(2)(x)`, which is different. It is assuming `runif(2)` is a function, and trying to pass the iterated value `1:3` in as the value of the first argument. In `purrr`, `runif(2)` is NOT a numeric vector. It has not yet been evaluated.

Comment: In `map`, you need to set `.default` to specify value for elements that are missing or `NULL`. To get the identical output as the first one, you need `map(1:3, runif(2), .default = integer(0))`.